# How can I convert IntBuffer to ByteBuffer without copying the data

Tags: java, scala, nio, bytebuffer, project-panama

My Scala/Java code has a large (several hundred megabytes) integer arrays. I would send these as fast as possible (without copying the contents) from this `int[]` using `java.nio`. Also, when I receive any data on my `nio` socket channels, I would use the data as `int[]` without copying.

All `nio` operations require `ByteBuffer`, while `ByteBuffer` can only wrap `byte []`.

I can allocate a `ByteBuffer`, then put my array using `asIntBuffer`, but it will copy the random array and I have to store my data twice.

```
    val size = 1234

    val random = Array.fill[Int](size) { scala.util.Random.nextInt(1000) }

    val buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * size)
    buf
      .asIntBuffer()
      .put(random)
```

I am using project panama openjdk, therefore any new trick (like using `Pointer<>`) could help me.

*TL;DR:* In Java or Scala, how can access my integer array as `ByteBuffer` and `int[]`.

Comment: Have you looked at the `wrap` method on IntBuffer and ByteBuffer?

Comment: ByteBuffer can only `wrap` byte arrays but not integers. IntBuffer can wrap integers but nio socket channels only accept ByteBuffer

Comment: How do you imagine this? You need convert one array of data to another array of data, you can't do this operation better than O(2n) memory consumption. Maybe the right direction to think is distribute your long array to some batches.

Comment: You don’t have to send the entire int array in one write call.  Allocate a ByteBuffer of a reasonable size (like four megabytes), use asIntBuffer.put to fill it with subsections of your int array, and send those subsections one at a time.  It’s likely that your network interface will be the bottleneck, not the speed of the program.

Comment: My whole point is to use as few copy ops as possible. My ideal scenario is to use `allocateDirect` in *Buffer, and use it for nio zero-copy while accessing its contents. The use case is: I am working on some MPI like message passing interface, while I need sometimes low latency and sometimes high throughput. Coming from other languages, `sendfile()`/zero copy is the way to go. Isn't this the same in JVM?

Comment: I understand your desire, but bulk copies are quite fast, and I’m pretty sure they’ll execute faster than your network can process them.